# async await does not work as i expect i am new to node js

Tags: node.js

here is my async await code it does not work as i expected can anyone help me please
my results are bellow

```
Start
end
waiting for 3000 miliseconds
```

but i expect it to work like this

```
Start
waiting for 3000 miliseconds
end
```

```
 function start(){
 console.log ('Start')
}


async function waittime(){
  let respone =await  setTimeout(()=>  {
      console.log('waiting for 3000 miliseconds')
    }, 3000);
    return respone
}



 function end(){
 console.log('end')
}

start();
waittime();
end();
```

Comment: we use `await` on promises, `setTimeout` doesnt return an promise

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned before setTimeout doesn't return a promise so awaiting it is redundant. You can wrap it into a new Promise constructor and return the result of the timeout on a `resolve()`. But still you would have the following:

NodeJS doesn't support high level await. Means you have to wrap it into an async function that always returns a Promise. This will make it impossible to call it in the same way.
You can however do this with two ways:

```js
// using then().catch() which you can use because async functions return Promises
start().then(() => waittime()).then(() => end());

// using an IIFE
(async function() {
   start();
   await waittime();
   end();
})()
```

I recommend you to read more about [Promises](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise) and [async/await](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function) there are some caveats that are important to know :)